# Change server manager rdp connecting port (azure)

Tags: port, azure, rdp

I have been trying to establish a remote desktop connection to a azure server using the server manager that is included in the rsat. But I havent find a way to connect to the server because my server isnt using the port 3389.

¿There is a way to change the default conecting rdp port in the server manager?

Answer (score 0):

Change the azure RDP endpoint with public port ANY PORT you want to connect and private port 3389. You should be able to connect RDP using the public port (of course after you allow that port in your local machine's firewall)

Comment: the problem is that server manager always will try to connect to the  azure vm with the port 3389, but the rdp port en azure are randomly assigned. so i need to configure server manager to connect to the "ANY PORT" that i have selected

Comment: try using ip:port when you insert server